# Non constant singular inner functions

Tags: complex-analysis

f is a non constant singular inner functions, then if $|a| < 1$ and $a \notin f(D)$, D is the unit disk, why $a$ must  $\in f(T)$, T is the unit cicrle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental result here is that if $S$ is a non-constant inner function st $\lim_{r \to 1}|S(re^{i\theta}| \ne 0$ for any $\theta \in \mathbb R$ (or more generally the non tangential limit is not zero at any point), then $S$ is a Blaschke product so in particular, $S$ has zeroes in the open unit disc (this essentially follows from the definition of a non trivial singular measure which implies that its derivative wr to the Lebesgue measure must be infinity on its support and then the non-tangential limit of the Poisson transform is infinity there and the non-tangential limit is the negative exponential of the Poisson transform so is zero).

But now if $f$ is a non constant singular inner function and $f(z) \ne a, |z|<1$ it follows that the shift $\frac{f(z)-a}{1-\bar a f(z)}$ which is inner, has no zeroes in the unit disc, so by the above, it must be zero on the boundary somewhere (where as usual the boundary values are defined by radial or non tangential limits and exist ae), so $a \in f(T)$ and we are done

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks Conrad. Actually, I already know non zeroes inner function g must have zero on the boundary, by ${1 \over g} \notin H^\infty $, I think about $f(z) - a$, but I cannot figure out the suitable transform to inner function, I cannot think out multiply with $\frac{1}{1-\bar a f(z)}$

Comment: Happy to help - note that for singular inner functions, most shifts by a complex number in the unit disc, give Blaschke products (which may not vanish on the circle) so here it is essential that $a$ is not in the image of the open disc to guarantee the shift is still singular